# Download logs from Pivotal CloudFoundry metrics API

Tags: metrics, cloud-foundry

Is there a API to download PCF logs from PCF metrics? I don't like the way that PCF metrics present to me, I would like to use splunk or other tools to analyzing logs.

I could use download button in metrics but I it's too manual.

Comment: Implement a firhose nozzle and you can consume it any tool of your choice - splunk, newrelic, prometheus and so on

Comment: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/firehose-to-syslog

Answer (score 0):

Any application running on Cloud Foundry can stream it's logs to any syslog comptabile service. Splunk has a syslog collector so you can follow the instructions here [app log streaming](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/log-management.html) Details for configuring this on PCF are at [enter link description here](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-0/devguide/services/integrate-splunk.html)

Comment: Does cloud foundry provide function to download logs? With certain filters.